# When using two different methods of finding the column space of a matrix, I get two different answers.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In my linear algebra class, I was taught two different methods of finding column space.

Method 1: If given matrix A, transpose A, then take the reduced-row echelon form. The non-zero rows of the resulting reduced-row echelon form will form the basis of the column space.

Method 2: If given matrix A, find the reduced-row echelon form. The columns with leading 1's will correspond to the pivot columns of the original matrix. These pivot columns form the basis of the column space.

There have been several problems in which using both methods results in different answers, which is very confusing for me. For example, when given the matrix \begin{bmatrix}1&1&-1\\1&2&1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix} both the original matrix and it's transpose have the reduced row echelon form to be the identity matrix. So, depending on which method is chosen, the column space could be {(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)} or {(1,1,0),(1,2,1),(-1,1,0)}. If there are matrices where the method chosen makes the answer different, which method should I use? I am quite confused on why two methods even exist in the first place, if they do not always result in the same answer. Is it because the answer to one method is a linear combination of the answer to the other method?

Comment: Your last line is correct!

Comment: Both of those sets of vectors generate the same vector space.  So, the individual vectors are different, but the space they define is the same.  So, it is the same answer.

Comment: Maybe your confusion comes from this description "forms **the** basis of the column space". It is not **the** basis. It is **a** basis. Vector spaces have many, many different bases. Any collection of linearly independent vectors that has as many vectors in it as the (finite) dimension of the vector space will form a basis of the vector space. So you cannot tell if two different sets of independent vectors of the same size form bases for the same vector space just by looking at them. The quickest way to tell is if the vectors of one can be expressed as combinations of vectors in the other.